# Azure Dev Ops pipeline fails when putting all my steps in a job

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, jobs

I have integration tests that I am able to run successfully in an ADO pipeline through a VMSS instance.
The tests pass just fine if I only use steps.
But when I put all my steps into a jobs > job, the tests fail.
Makes no sense why to me.
Is there a reasons my tests fail when running in jobs and not in steps alone?
Some context on my tests:

- These tests use a postgresdb in a docker container that I spin up. This still works. Pretty sure this is not the problem. The tests themselves do not run in a container.
- These tests use ENV vars for settings for my code, this still works.
- The tests access key vault, this still works.
- The tests spin up flask container using specific unused ports to test API responses at a high leve. all the flask containers run in gevents. This works fine on any other system.
- All tests are run with pytest via a tox env.
- I have tested going directly to the VMSS instance and running my tests, works fine.
- I tested running with steps with an ADO pipeline, this works fine.
- Second I put it into a job it fails at random points.

Here is the pipeline that works:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: ourpool

steps:
  - script: |
      sudo -i apt install -y python3.9 python3-pip python3.9-venv
      python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
      pip install pip --upgrade
    displayName: "install python3.9"

   - script: |
      pip3 install .
      pip3 install ./client
      pip3 install tox
    displayName: "Create Override and Install Dependencies for testing"

    - script: |
      docker stop pgdb
      docker rm pgdb
      docker run --name pgdb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d ourdb
    displayName: "Start Postgres Docker Container"

  - script: |
      export PATH=$PATH:/home/User/.local/bin
      export APP__CONF__01="cat"
      export APP__CONF__02="dog"
      export APP__CONF__03="moose"
      tox -e integration_tests
      TOXCODE=$?
      echo $TOXCODE
      exit $TOXCODE
    timeoutInMinutes: 15
    displayName: "Test - integration"

  - script: |
      docker stop postgres-db
    displayName: "Stop Postgres Docker Container"

  - task: AzureKeyVault@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: "oursub"
      KeyVaultName: "ourkeyvault"
      SecretsFilter: "*"
      RunAsPreJob: true
    displayName: "Get KeyVault Secrets"
```

However when I change it to the following tests fail randomly

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: ourpool

jobs:
- job: IntegrationTests
  displayName: "Run Integration Tests"
  steps:
    - script: |
        sudo -i apt install -y python3.9 python3-pip python3.9-venv
        python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pip --upgrade
      displayName: "install python3.9"

    - script: |
        pip3 install .
        pip3 install ./client
        pip3 install tox
      displayName: "Create Override and Install Dependencies for testing"

    - script: |
        docker stop pgdb
        docker rm pgdb
        docker run --name pgdb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 -d ourdb
      displayName: "Start Postgres Docker Container"

    - script: |
        export PATH=$PATH:/home/User/.local/bin
        export APP__CONF__01="cat"
        export APP__CONF__02="dog"
        export APP__CONF__03="moose"
        tox -e integration_tests
        TOXCODE=$?
        echo $TOXCODE
        exit $TOXCODE
      timeoutInMinutes: 15
      displayName: "Test - integration"

    - script: |
        docker stop pgdb
      displayName: "Stop Postgres Docker Container"

    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: "oursub"
        KeyVaultName: "ourkeyvault"
        SecretsFilter: "*"
        RunAsPreJob: true
      displayName: "Get KeyVault Secrets"
```

Are jobs doing something different with resources in some strange way? Are they run differently? I want to run these tests directly in the VMSS as a job but I am not sure what Azure is doing differently with this tests compared to ones that are just steps. Can anyone help?

Comment: I can't think of any reason why moving your steps into a parent job would cause failure., your syntax looks correct to me. Can you give some more context into the failure you are receiving? Are you sure it is to do with the pipeline, and not unstable tests?

Comment: Hi guys, Even the working pipeline didn't have `jobs` section, the pipeline would be expanded with default `stages` and `jobs` at compile time. I suspect the two pipelines were running on different agents from `ourpool`. May I know if there were multiple agents in this self-hosted agent pool? Would you please check the `Initialize job` step (usually before `checkout`) of the pipeline logs, where you can find and compare the agent names with machine names between the succeeded and failed pipeline logs?

Comment: If the agents were different, you may consider using [poo.demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool-demands?view=azure-pipelines) to configure the pipeline running on a selected agent.

Comment: I deleted my answer, it was not correct. Really this post is not correct. Tests fail in tasks or jobs. Its not a jobs problem. I am still having the issue. However after doing more trouble shooting I think it maybe related to a few things. (1) using gevent instead of threads (2) possibly related to the way we log output (print statements instead of using logger). I made changes to test more but, unfortunately I cant test right now as a recent merge broke our testing. However once this is fixed I can try some new testing. Will update the post when I find out more.